# Are there crosses or alternatives for the IP5311CX5_LF LCD display chip for Nokia 6120c Classic (year 2008 model)?

Tags: integrated-circuit, lcd

I was looking for the LCD display chip for my Nokia 6120c Classic (model year 2008).

The name of this chip as shown in this schematic diagram of Nokia 6120c Classic (model year 2008) is IP5311CX5_LF as shown in the picture below.

[image: Schematic]

How can I find this chip or a suitable cross for it? I need it to repair my phone. What is this chip?

Comment: This is an international site (it's not afternoon here). This is a Q&A, not a forum (so don't waste time with greetings). Instead of adding thanks, vote on and accept answers that you find helpful. And finally, please crop images to the relevant portion.

Comment: @JYelton thanks for the tips!

Comment: To clarify, are you asking what the function of the chip is? Shopping questions (where to purchase X) are off-topic. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: https://octopart.com/search?q=IP5311CX5

Comment: @JYelton That's right. I believe that the IP5311CX5_LF is an LCD display chip but I was wondering if that chip is really an LCD Chip...so I would like to confirm. Been looking for that chip in search results in the Internet but nothing came up. Probably it might have other names.

Comment: @nanash1 good one! I'm going to list those manufacturers that have that IP5311CX5_LF chip so I may have many options. Thank you!

Comment: @fitzmerl_duron `Been looking for that chip in search results in the Internet but nothing came up` Really? If you search for 'IP5311CX5' all the first results have [datasheets](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/916/IP5311CX5-1389025.pdf).

Comment: @nanash1 I'm surprised that in my side, nothing came up. I find it weird that nothing came up in the search result. But it's good that I came here. Thank you for assistance!

Comment: @nanash1 I have a question. Is the IP5311CX5_LF chip an LCD display chip or a low pass filter chip? Thanks!

Comment: @JYelton I have a question. Is the IP5311CX5_LF chip an LCD display chip or a low pass filter chip? Thanks!

Comment: @LightningThrows It's just a passive filter like the datasheet says. Looking at the schematic, it's used for the audio jack here. It has nothing to do with the LCD display.